# Convert.ToDecimal(String.Format("{0:.##}", doubleAmount)) doesn't like 0.0

Tags: c#, .net

I have a formatting problem with this line:

```
Decimal amount = Convert.ToDecimal(String.Format("{0:.##}", doubleAmount));
```

If `doubleAmount` is 0.0, it throws a format exception. How do I handle 0.0?

Comment: Use `{0:0.##}` to ensure there's at least one digit.

Comment: Try `{0:#.##}` to accommodate the integer component.

Comment: Assuming `doubleAmount` is a double, why are you converting it to a string and then to a `Decimal` rather than directly to a `Decimal`?

Comment: Yes, `doubleAmount` is a double. If you have a more efficient method, please show it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the format string `{0:.##}` formats 0 as an empty string, but
an empty string is not a valid argument for `Convert.ToDecimal`. To avoid a possible FormatException, you can use `{0:0.##}` to format 0 as `0`.

(User sasfrog suggests `{0:#.##}`, but since that also formats 0 as an empty string, it doesn't work.)

However, if you're just trying to round a Double value to two decimal places and store the result in a Decimal variable, then you should use

```
Decimal amount = Decimal.Round((Decimal)doubleAmount, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

and skip the unnecessary overhead of string formatting and parsing.